# SUBTOTAL where dates are between a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

im doing some calculations in excel and noticed there were way off what i was expecting i was using this formula calculate the sum for values between a date range:

```
=SUMIFS(V496:V57573,U496:U57573,">"&"01/01/2020",U496:U57573,"<"&"29/02/2020")
```

i think i should be using the SUBTOTAL to do it on the filtered data so i get the result for that subset. 
How would i use the subtotal to have it where its in that date range on an already filtered data set

Comment: yeah id deleted where it was = to a name as i fileter to that so shouldnt need it when using subtotal. removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the rows and check if hidden, then use some Boolean with SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(V496,ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,ROWS(V496:V57573)))-1,0,1,1)))*(U496:U57573>DATE(2020,1,1))*(U496:U57573< DATE(2020,2,29))*V496:V57573)
```

Comment: thanks do you know how i would edit this for a before/after x just the one date ?

Comment: just change the Booleans: `(U496:U57573>DATE(2020,1,1))*(U496:U57573< DATE(2020,2,29))` to match what you want.